# SQL query to get columns of a composite index

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2022

The following query returns the columns of a composite index in multiple rows.

Question: how can we write a query that returns all columns of a composite index in one row?

Example:

```
create table #t
(
    c int, 
    d varchar(5), 
    e varchar(10)
)

create index idx_test on #t (d, e)
```

Running the following query on `tempdb` returns two rows for the same index. I would like it to return one row under header `column_names` containing the columns d and e separated by `,` such as `e,d`

```
SELECT 
    i.name AS index_name,
    COL_NAME(ic.object_id, ic.column_id) AS column_names
FROM 
    sys.indexes AS i
INNER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns AS ic ON i.object_id = ic.object_id 
                            AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
WHERE 
    i.object_id = OBJECT_ID('#t');
```

Output:

| index_name | column_names |
| --- | --- |
| idx_test | d |
| idx_test | e |

Desired output:

```
|      index_name     |     column_names |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          idx_test   |         d,e      |
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `STRING_AGG` in your query and group by the index name - try this code:

```
SELECT 
    i.name AS index_name,
    STRING_AGG(COL_NAME(ic.object_id, ic.column_id), ', ') AS column_names
FROM 
    sys.indexes AS i
INNER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns AS ic ON i.object_id = ic.object_id 
                            AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
WHERE 
    -- updated to keep siggemannen happy ;-) 
    i.object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t')
    -- or alternatively: use the known index name; there could be more than 1 index on that table ...
    -- i.name = 'idx_test'
GROUP BY
    i.name;
```

Comment: Just a little nitpick, but you need to be in tempdb for the above to work. I usually always prefix sys.indexes etc with tempdb. Same goes for OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t')

Comment: @marc_s Your suggestion is working when I run it in `tempdb` - which is ok for me. But before marking it as an `answer`, I thought I ask you the following: Since you have prefixed #t with tempdb, I thought, I would not have to change the db context to tempdb. I tried prefixing sys.indexes with tempdb, as well but it still returned empty result. On tempdb. it worked with or without prefixing #t with tempdb. I was wondering why prefixing with tempdb (while working on a different db context) does not work.